# iOS Error in main.m — “Program received ”SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, xcode, sigabrt

I am new to xcode 4.5

I am developing an app and it stops with a *runtime error* **SIGABRT**.

This is the code where the error occurred in the main.m file...

```
// ***********************************************************
//  main.m
//  ex21
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ex21AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ex21AppDelegate class]));

        //Login *login1 = [[Login alloc]init];
        //[login1 setLoginid:@"Sam"];
        //[login1 setPassword:ca@"test1"];
        //NSLog(@"Login ID = %@, Password = %@",[login1 loginid], [login1 password]);

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ex21AppDelegate class]));

    }
}


// ***********************************************************
//  ex21AppDelegate.h
//  ex21
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ex21AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end


// ***********************************************************
//  ex21AppDelegate.m
//  ex21
//

#import "ex21AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ex21AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end


// ***********************************************************
//  ex21MainMenu.h
//  ex21
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ex21MainMenu : UIView {

}

-(IBAction)hyperlink;

@end


// ***********************************************************
//
//  ex21MainMenu.m
//  ex21
//

#import "ex21MainMenu.h"

@implementation ex21MainMenu

- (IBAction)hyperlink {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end



// ***********************************************************
//  ex21ViewController.h
//  ex21
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ex21ViewController:  UITableViewController

@end


// ***********************************************************
//  ex21ViewController.m
//  ex21
//

#import "ex21ViewController.h"

@interface ex21ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ex21ViewController

- (IBAction)doneWithKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

**I prevented the code above from importing the code below because I decided not to use it.**

```
// ***********************************************************
//  Login.h
//  ex21
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Login : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *loginid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *password;

- (id)initWithLoginID:(NSString *)loginid
             password:(NSString *)password;
@end

// ***********************************************************
//  Login.m
//  ex21
//

#import "Login.h"

@implementation Login

@synthesize loginid = _loginid;
@synthesize password = _password;

- (id)initWithLoginID:(NSString *)loginid
             password:(NSString *)password
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        _loginid = loginid;
        _password = password;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

=======================================

The *Exception State Registers* indicated the following:

- **rapno** (unsigned int)
- **err** (unsigned int)
- **faultvaddr** (unsigned int)

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: At a SIGABRT error, it always shows the main, but that's not the source of the issue. Could you track down where in your project it's occurring. It's usually something like referencing an uninitialised variable. There should be more information in the debugger console.

Comment: I removed the code that initialize the variables because I no longer plan to use them. If I comment out the above code, then another error occurs at compile time. Do I need to use the code above? Again, please note that I am new to xcode.

Comment: Start by not changing the code and adding an exception breakpoint.  Follow instructions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html  set it up for "all exceptions".  Then you can post here the code where it breaks.

Comment: Daniel's right.  check the console window in xcode, it should have more information than what you have here.  Some errors that happen elsewhere end up in the spot yours does, and this spot almost never is the cause of the problem.

Comment: As clarification. SIGABRT is a Signal to Abort. When an app aborts, the line it's aborted on is in the main.m - this is because, it's the master line of the app. You'll do well not to touch the main.m at all because adjusting it could break your app - I'm 99.9% sure the place your error occurred was not in main.m - check the console and as @danh said, add an Exception Breakpoint to clarify.

Comment: I tried the **Exception Breakpoint** I am not sure what I am doing. So  see the entire main.m code above.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in main function (except double-return o.O). Try to use the Exception Breakpoint once more and then type `bt` in the console to see the backtrace. Then put it here.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised you'd put actual application logic into the main.m - you should try to keep the main.m free from logic and program your logic directly into a UIViewController class for example.

Comment: After looking at your code, and being a beginner, you should get and follow one of the beginning books on beginning iPhone programming, as there's a lot of lore that you need to know before you start, like the MVC concept and how to work with viewControllers.  I'd recommend the books by David Mark, or Aaron Hillegass. Or, watch the free course from Stanford University on how to program iOS.  You'll save a lot of time.

Comment: I started the project over since it is a simple app. **No errors**. Owen, I will buy some books as you suggested. I need to learn more about the subject matter. Thank you all for your help. Here is a simple question: Will iphone 5 apps using the full screen real estate be able to run on iphone 4 and 4S?